# scrollLeft on horizontal website with white-space: nowrap doesn't work

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I got a problem with a horizontally scrolling website. I use the following code for the site wrapper:

```
#site {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
position:relative;
background: #fff;
}
```

and inline-block for all the container inside. This all works great. What doesn't work is when I try to add a navigation with smooth scrolling like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.scroll').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
    }, 1200);
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I actually know, that the body doesn't really stretch to the width of the inline-block elements but maybe there is a little tweak I didn't think about? When I set the #site to a fixed width it works, but I can't do that, since the site is responsive.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.scroll').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('#site').animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
    }, 1200);
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When I change the function like this the offset gets all messed up, depending on where on the site I am at the time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.